# Count of active user sessions per hour

Tags: sql, postgresql

For each user login to our website, we insert a record into our user_session table with the user's login and logout timestamps.  If I wanted to produce a graph of the number of logins per hour over time, it would be easy with the following SQL.

```
SELECT
  date_trunc('hour',login_time) AS "time",
  count(*)
FROM user_session
group by time
order by time
```

Time would be the X-axis and count would be the Y-axis.

But what I really need is the number of active sessions in each hour where "active" means
login_time <= foo and logout_time >= foo where foo is the particular time slot.

How can I do this in a single SELECT statement?

Answer (score 1):

One brute force method generates the hours and then uses a lateral join or correlated subquery to do the calculation:

```
select gs.ts, us.num_active
from generate_series('2021-03-21'::timestamp, '2021-03-22'::timestamp, interval '1 hour') gs(ts) left join lateral
     (select count(*) as num_active
      from user_session us
      where us.login_time <= gs.ts and
            us.logout_time > gs.ts
     ) us
     on 1=1;
```

A more efficient method -- particularly for longer periods of time -- is to pivot the times and keep an incremental count is ins and outs:

```
with cte as (
      select date_trunc('hour', login_time) as hh, count(*) as inc
      from user_session
      group by hh
      select date_trunc('hour', logout_time + interval '1 hour') as hh, - count(*) as inc
      from user_session
      group by hh
     )
select hh, sum(inc) as net_in_hour,
       sum(sum(inc)) over (order by hh) as active_in_hour
from cte
group by hh;
```

Comment: Thank you!

I commented out the first select, and removed the dash before the count in the second.  It works.